# How to fix my Greatest Common Divisor Code? It works for all numbers except zero and zero

Tags: c++

The basic program I created below calculates the greatest common divisor for 2 integers.  It work fine for all numbers except the specific combination of zero and zero.  I'm pretty sure something is wrong with the if statement in the function "greatComDiv()" but I can't figure out what is wrong with it specifically.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int greatComDiv(int num1, int num2)
{
//The 2 lines below convert the numbers to their absolute value in case they are negative

num1 = abs(num1);
num2 = abs(num2);

//The if statement below takes care of the case that both numbers are zero the subsequent else statement performs the normal calculations if they are both not zero.

    if( num1== 0 && num2 == 0)
    {
      cout<<"undefined"<<endl;  
    }

    else
    {
      while(num2 > 0 )
        {
        num1%num2;
        int  tempNum = num1%num2;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = tempNum;            
        }  
       return num1;
    }
 }

int main()
{  

int numb1, numb2;

cout<<"Enter 2 numbers -->";
cin>>numb1>>numb2;

cout<<"GCD("<<numb1<<", "<<numb2<<") = "<<greatComDiv(numb1,numb2)<<endl;

}
```

For example this is a test run with the numbers 3 and 9:

```
Enter 2 numbers -->3 9
GCD(3, 9) = 3

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3s)
```

Another test run with the numbers 100 and -150

```
Enter 2 numbers -->100 -150
GCD(100, -150) = 50

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3s)
```

This is one more test run with the numbers 0 and -9.

```
Enter 2 numbers -->0 -9
GCD(0, -9) = 9

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)
```

However, this is what happens when I enter 0 and 0

```
Enter 2 numbers -->0 0
GCD(0, 0) = Undefined
-18165920
```

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)

Why is the number -18165920 showing up at the bottom?  It has to be the if statement because this only happens for specifically 0 and 0, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: What does `greatComDiv` return when one of the parms is 0?

Comment: Enable warnings for your compiler

Comment: `In mathematics, the greatest common divisor (gcd) of two or more integers, which are not all zero, is the largest positive integer that divides each of the integers.`. So your problem isn't the "program", it's your assumption. `which are not all zero` is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

You should return something on your function. In your special case you are not retuning anything, that must be why that number is being printed. Also it is not a good practice to print something in a function that should only return some result. Try this:

```
int greatComDiv(int num1, int num2)
{
//The 2 lines below convert the numbers to their absolute value in case they are negative

num1 = abs(num1);
num2 = abs(num2);

//The if statement below takes care of the case that both numbers are zero the subsequent else statement performs the normal calculations if they are both not zero.

if( num1== 0 && num2 == 0)
{
  return 0;
}

else
{
  while(num2 > 0 )
    {
    num1%num2;
    int  tempNum = num1%num2;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = tempNum;            
    }  
   return num1;
}
}
```

Then "catch" you exception in your main code:

```
int main()
{  

int numb1, numb2, gcd;

cout<<"Enter 2 numbers -->";
cin>>numb1>>numb2;

gcd = greatComDiv(numb1,numb2);
if(gdc == 0) {
    cout<<"GCD("<<numb1<<", "<<numb2<<") = undefined"<<endl;
} else {
    cout<<"GCD("<<numb1<<", "<<numb2<<") = "<<gcd<<endl;
}

}
```